# I want to insert an image from cloud in power bi using this html js code - custom visual

Tags: javascript, html, image, powerbi, visualization

I am using d3.js custom visual, and inserting this code through a measure into this custom visual.

I donot see the output, where as there are no errors in the script as well.
any alternative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div id="htmlContent">
        <div class="htmlViewerEntry">
        <div>
        <script src=https://product-gallery.cloudinary.com/all.js type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                 const myGallery = cloudinary.galleryWidget({
                   container: "#my-gallery",
                   cloudName: "cavenders",
                   mediaAssets: [{
                     tag: "00032"
                   }]
                 });
                 myGallery.render();
        </script>
        <div id="my-gallery" style="max-width:80%;margin:auto">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This code either gives me no image or the entire code as output.

I tried using html content, d3.js custom visuals.